# regression model behaves (predicts) like classification

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, data-science-model

I have a simple data:

```
data = {
'X':   [],
'y':  []
    }


data['X'].extend(   [1,     3,     6,    10,   20,    30,    45,   60,    95,   115,    190, ])
data['y'].extend(   [80,    60,    41,   27,   20,    16,    11,   8.5,   7.7,  6.8,    5.6, ])


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
X = df.drop(columns='y', axis=1).values
y = df['y'].values
```

I make a simple model

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
regr_XGBR = XGBRegressor()
regr_XGBR.fit(X, y)
```

A plot looks perfect

```
plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.plot(X, regr_XGBR.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

After I try to predict some values, the result looks like a classification model (similar to KNeighbors).
Also I tried with poly but nothing changed.

```
print(regr_XGBR.predict(([[3]])))
print(regr_XGBR.predict(([[3.2]])))
print(regr_XGBR.predict(([[3.5]])))
print(regr_XGBR.predict(([[4]])))
print(regr_XGBR.predict(([[4.2]])))

[59.874977]
[59.874977]
[59.874977]
[59.874977]
[59.874977]
```

PS I spent a lot of time trying to solve this problem and got stuck. I would be glad to know at least a direction in solving this issue.

PSS Also I tried to search for similar problems but didn't find anything similar to my issue.

I will be glad for any help!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the behaviour you are seeing, it is simply caused by the fact that you have very few datapoints and only a single feature. Because of this, the outputs of your model will not be very smooth over the full range of your input feature. This can be seen quite clearly in the following plot:

[image]

If you want to have a smoother line you would need more data points that give the model more information about what the expected values would be in between your current points. In addition, the line will never be perfectly smooth when using trees because of the way tree segment the data.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot! Сan you tell me please  how to build a plot like yours?

Comment: The following code should work: `plt.plot(np.arange(1, 190, 0.5), regr_XGBR.predict(np.arange(1, 190, 0.5).reshape(-1, 1))`.

Comment: Thanks! I finally figured it out